# OAuth2 Issue with gData ContactsService

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, gdata, google-contacts-api

I am receiving an exception when trying to authenticate and make a single call with the java client libraries (gData 1.47.1) using OAuth2.  The following is the exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: No authentication header information
at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.initFromAuthHeader(AuthenticationException.java:96)
at com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException.<init>(AuthenticationException.java:67)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:608)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.handleErrorResponse(GoogleGDataRequest.java:564)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.checkResponse(HttpGDataRequest.java:560)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.HttpGDataRequest.execute(HttpGDataRequest.java:538)
at com.google.gdata.client.http.GoogleGDataRequest.execute(GoogleGDataRequest.java:536)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1135)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:998)
at com.google.gdata.client.GoogleService.getFeed(GoogleService.java:645)
at com.google.gdata.client.Service.getFeed(Service.java:1017)
at com.test.Main.main(Main.java:79)
```

Code to create service :

```
String scope = "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds";

ContactsService service = new ContactsService("APP_NAME");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(getCredential(scope, userEmail));


public GoogleCredential getCredential(ArrayList<String> scopes, String userEmail) throws Exception {
        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT).setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setServiceAccountId(this.serviceAccountEmail).setServiceAccountScopes(scopes).setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(f)
                .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail).build();
        return credential;
    }
```

Call Made :

```
URL feedUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full");
        ContactFeed resultFeed = service.getFeed(feedUrl, ContactFeed.class);
```

I have also enabled the Contacts API in my apps console for this project as stated in the documentation.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened to me. I fixed it by refreshing the token when it is near expiration.

```
if (credential != null && (credential.getExpiresInSeconds() == null || credential.getExpiresInSeconds() < 5)) {
    credential.refreshToken();
}
```

IMO, the newer google-api-client-java does this automatically, while Gdata doesn't.